# PHP get file from Google maps and return it

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps

I'm developing a web-service in `PHP` where I generate a URL for [google static maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1)
For example:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

I need to get that `png` image and return it as image:

```
$fullURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false';
$img = file_get_contents($fullURL);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($img));
echo $img;
```

when I run the google url in browser I see the image and get:
[image]

but when I run my page with the code above I don't see the image and it's size is different:
[image]

**How to do that right?

(my service suppose to return the same as google original url, png file).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `filesize()` on the image content. Try using `strlen()` or similar:

```
$fullURL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false';
$img = file_get_contents($fullURL);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($img));
echo $img;
```